# Поиск взаимосвязи между A и B объектами

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

хотел бы спросить а есть ли какой-то алгоритм который можно применить для следующей задачи. Есть массив объектов у которых есть ключ borders который указывает на связи с другими объектами этого массива, нужно выстроить путь от и до указанных имен объектов.

```js
const arrOfObjects = [
    {name: 'a', borders: ['c', 'd']},
    {name: 'b', borders: ['d', 'e']},
    {name: 'c', borders: ['a', 'f']},
    {name: 'd', borders: ['a', 'b']},
    {name: 'e', borders: ['b', 'g']},
    {name: 'f', borders: ['c', 'e']},
    {name: 'g', borders: ['e', '']},
]
// То-есть он должен вернуть массив 
findRoad('a', 'g')
/* Вернуть массив вот такого вида
[
{name: 'a', borders: ['c', 'd']},
{name: 'c', borders: ['a', 'f']},
{name: 'f', borders: ['c', 'e']},
{name: 'e', borders: ['b', 'g']},
{name: 'g', borders: ['e', '']},
]


*/
```

Взаимосвязей у объекта может не быть или быть больше*

Comment: Я вижу решение только через рекурсию такой алгоритм написать.

Comment: это называется граф с вершинами и ребрами. Задачи поиска путей в графе обычно сводятсяк двум - поиск кратчайшего пути, либо поиску всех путей. Графы могут быть направленными, когда в одну сторону двигаться можно, а в обратную нет. Еще там есть всякое про связность, и про прочее.

Comment: то есть вам надо взять учебник по теории графов и изучаить что есть что и посмотреть на алгоритмы для поиска. Вся соль там обычно в отмечании уже помещенных вершин при поиске пути

Comment: Понял, спасибо, *надо было в проститутки идти*

Comment: прям учебник можно и не читать, конечно, но термины и определения чтобы понимать надо прочесть какую нить статью. А то найдете алгоритм для взвещенного ориентированного графа, а у вас тут и неориентированый и без весов. Так что почитать про графы,  а потом про Дейкстру

Comment: Чтобы найти путь от и до, вы можете просто реализовать поиск в ширину